# Data is not sorting properly on page load

Tags: datatables

I am having trouble sorting a data table on entry. My code:

```
$('#CommentsOnAuthors').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/authors_comments',
    data: {
      author_id: "#{author_id}",
      book_id: "#{book_id}"
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {title: 'Date', data: 'created_at', type: 'date'},
    {title: 'Book', data: 'book'},
    {title: 'Author', data: 'author'},
    {title: 'Comment', data: 'comment'}
  ],
  order: [[1, 'desc']]
});
```

However, when the page loads, the second column (Book) is sorted in ascending order (and the down arrow for that column is bolded), not the first. If I click on the arrow of the first column (Date), it sorts it properly. I believe I am following the documentation. I would like the table to load, sorted by Date, in descending order. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are zero-based, like arrays. So if you want to sort by the date you need to do

```
order: [[0, 'desc']]
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. The examples I saw on the forum, said 1